# How can I get Eclipse to recognize the most recent Hadoop libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

This question is more of an Eclipse question, but those who have worked with Hadoop may know the answer.

Last year, I wrote some Hadoop MapReduce jobs in Eclipse.  To access the libraries and packages I needed to compile the code, I installed an Eclipse plug-in off the Apache website (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn).  Unfortunately, that plug-in isn’t compatible with the latest version of Hadoop (the 2.0.0-alpha version).  I was wondering if anyone had done any work with writing Hadoop jobs within the past few months, and knows how I can get Eclipse to recognize the most recent Hadoop (2.0.0-alpha) packages.

The plug-in still works for Hadoop 0.20.203.0, but I was hoping to be able to use the newest version.

I'm running Eclipse in Windows.  I tried right-clicking on the name of my project, going to `Properties` then to `Java Build Path` and finally selecting `Add External JARs` 
I added all the JARs from the `hadoop-2.0.0-alpha/share/hadoop` directory and subdirectories.  At first, I thought this had worked, but when I try to use methods and constructors unique to the Hadoop 2.0.0-alpha API, the code does not compile.  The libraries it is recognizing are definitely more recent than those from Hadoop 0.20.203.0, but not as recent as the current alpha version of Hadoop.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: What's in your current Build Path's Library tab?

Comment: All of the JARs from the hadoop-2.0.0-alpha/share/hadoop directory and subdirectories.  Are there more that I should add?

Comment: Can you screenshot and post somewhere?